# H2O R api: retrieving optimal model from grid search

Tags: python, r, h2o

I'm using the `h2o` package (v 3.6.0) in R, and I've built a grid search model. Now, I'm trying to access the model which minimizes MSE on the validation set. In python's `sklearn`, this is easily achievable when using `RandomizedSearchCV`:

```
## Pseudo code:
grid = RandomizedSearchCV(model, params, n_iter = 5)
grid.fit(X)
best = grid.best_estimator_
```

This, unfortunately, does not prove as straightforward in h2o. Here's an example you can recreate:

```
library(h2o)
## assume you got h2o initialized...

X <- as.h2o(iris[1:100,]) # Note: only using top two classes for example 
grid <- h2o.grid(
    algorithm = 'gbm',
    x = names(X[,1:4]),
    y = 'Species',
    training_frame = X,
    hyper_params = list(
        distribution = 'bernoulli',
        ntrees = c(25,50)
    )
)
```

Viewing `grid` prints a wealth of information, including this portion:

```
> grid
ntrees distribution status_ok                                                                 model_ids
 50    bernoulli        OK Grid_GBM_file1742e107fe5ba_csv_10.hex_11_model_R_1456492736353_16_model_1
 25    bernoulli        OK Grid_GBM_file1742e107fe5ba_csv_10.hex_11_model_R_1456492736353_16_model_0
```

With a bit of digging, you can access each individual model and view every metric imaginable:

```
> h2o.getModel(grid@model_ids[[1]])
H2OBinomialModel: gbm
Model ID:  Grid_GBM_file1742e107fe5ba_csv_10.hex_11_model_R_1456492736353_18_model_1 
Model Summary: 
  number_of_trees model_size_in_bytes min_depth max_depth mean_depth min_leaves max_leaves mean_leaves
1              50                4387         1         1    1.00000          2          2     2.00000


H2OBinomialMetrics: gbm
** Reported on training data. **

MSE:  1.056927e-05
R^2:  0.9999577
LogLoss:  0.003256338
AUC:  1
Gini:  1

Confusion Matrix for F1-optimal threshold:
           setosa versicolor    Error    Rate
setosa         50          0 0.000000   =0/50
versicolor      0         50 0.000000   =0/50
Totals         50         50 0.000000  =0/100

Maximum Metrics: Maximum metrics at their respective thresholds
                      metric threshold    value idx
1                     max f1  0.996749 1.000000   0
2                     max f2  0.996749 1.000000   0
3               max f0point5  0.996749 1.000000   0
4               max accuracy  0.996749 1.000000   0
5              max precision  0.996749 1.000000   0
6           max absolute_MCC  0.996749 1.000000   0
7 max min_per_class_accuracy  0.996749 1.000000   0
```

And with a ***lot*** of digging, you can finally get to this:

```
> h2o.getModel(grid@model_ids[[1]])@model$training_metrics@metrics$MSE
[1] 1.056927e-05
```

This seems like a lot of kludgey work to get down to a metric that ought to be top-level for model selection. In my situation, I've got a grid with hundreds of models, and my current, hacky solution just doesn't seems very "R-esque":

```
model_select_ <- function(grid) {
  model_ids <- grid@model_ids
  min = Inf
  best_model = NULL

  for(model_id in model_ids) {
    model <- h2o.getModel(model_id)
    mse <- model@model$training_metrics@metrics$MSE
    if(mse < min) {
      min <- mse
      best_model <- model
    }
  }

  best_model
}
```

This seems like overkill for something that is so core to the practice of machine learning, and it just strikes me as odd that h2o would not have a "cleaner" method of extracting the optimal model, or at least model metrics.

Am I missing something? Is there no "out of the box" method for selecting the best model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is an easy way to extract the "top" model of an H2O grid search.  There are also utility functions that will extract all the model metrics (e.g. `h2o.mse`) that you have been trying to access.  Examples of how to do these things can be found in the [h2o-r/demos](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/tree/master/h2o-r/demos) and [h2o-py/demos](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/tree/master/h2o-py/demos) subfolders on the [h2o-3](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3) GitHub repo.

Since you are using R, here is a [relevant code example](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-r/demos/H2O_tutorial_eeg_eyestate_NOPASS.ipynb) that includes a grid search, with sorted results.  You can also find how to access this information in the R documentation for the `h2o.getGrid` function.

Print out the auc for all of the models, sorted by validation AUC:

```
auc_table <- h2o.getGrid(grid_id = "eeg_demo_gbm_grid", sort_by = "auc", decreasing = TRUE)
print(auc_table)
```

Here is an example of the output:

```
H2O Grid Details
================

Grid ID: eeg_demo_gbm_grid 
Used hyper parameters: 
  -  ntrees 
  -  max_depth 
  -  learn_rate 
Number of models: 18 
Number of failed models: 0 

Hyper-Parameter Search Summary: ordered by decreasing auc
   ntrees max_depth learn_rate                  model_ids               auc
1     100         5        0.2 eeg_demo_gbm_grid_model_17 0.967771493797284
2      50         5        0.2 eeg_demo_gbm_grid_model_16 0.949609591795923
3     100         5        0.1  eeg_demo_gbm_grid_model_8  0.94941792664595
4      50         5        0.1  eeg_demo_gbm_grid_model_7 0.922075196552274
5     100         3        0.2 eeg_demo_gbm_grid_model_14 0.913785959685157
6      50         3        0.2 eeg_demo_gbm_grid_model_13 0.887706691652792
7     100         3        0.1  eeg_demo_gbm_grid_model_5 0.884064379717198
8       5         5        0.2 eeg_demo_gbm_grid_model_15 0.851187402678818
9      50         3        0.1  eeg_demo_gbm_grid_model_4 0.848921799270639
10      5         5        0.1  eeg_demo_gbm_grid_model_6 0.825662907513139
11    100         2        0.2 eeg_demo_gbm_grid_model_11 0.812030639460551
12     50         2        0.2 eeg_demo_gbm_grid_model_10 0.785379521713437
13    100         2        0.1  eeg_demo_gbm_grid_model_2  0.78299280750123
14      5         3        0.2 eeg_demo_gbm_grid_model_12 0.774673686150002
15     50         2        0.1  eeg_demo_gbm_grid_model_1 0.754834657912535
16      5         3        0.1  eeg_demo_gbm_grid_model_3 0.749285131682721
17      5         2        0.2  eeg_demo_gbm_grid_model_9 0.692702793188135
18      5         2        0.1  eeg_demo_gbm_grid_model_0 0.676144542037133
```

The top row in the table contains the model with the best AUC, so below we can grab that model and extract the validation AUC:

```
best_model <- h2o.getModel(auc_table@model_ids[[1]])
h2o.auc(best_model, valid = TRUE)
```

In order for the `h2o.getGrid` function to be able sort by a metric on the validation set, you need to actually pass the `h2o.grid` function a `validation_frame`.  In your example above, you did not pass a validation_frame, so you can't evaluate the models in the grid on the validation set.

Comment: This is great, Erin. In the reproducible example I didn't pass a validation set, but in my actual code I did. Thank you!

Comment: H2O.grid() does not use validation_frame, actually. It uses training_frame only.  It ignores the validation_frame which you pass in for scoring purposes. The resulting model is overfitted, naturally, and therefore it is useless. Has this problem been fixed yet?  You can look at your winning model from the search and directly see its scoring progression to compare for example the training_auc and the validation_auc. You will see the problem if you look there.

Comment: @GeoffreyAnderson We have a ticket open to track your observations/issues with the `validation_frame` and `h2o.grid` and hope to resolve that shortly. You can follow the progress here: https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-4035

Comment: @Erin L. Thank you for looking into.   FYI the model training functions (e.g. h2o.gbm(), h2o.randomForest()) and not the grid per se is the actual source of the problem as I perceive it according to continuing research I have done on it.  I look keenly toward fixing my user error if any or fixing with some workaround any software error if any.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be valid for recent versions of h2o only, with 3.8.2.3 you get 
a Java exception saying that "auc" is an invalid metric.
The following fails :

```
library(h2o)
library(jsonlite)
h2o.init()
iris.hex <- as.h2o(iris)
h2o.grid("gbm", grid_id = "gbm_grid_id", x = c(1:4), y = 5,
     training_frame = iris.hex, hyper_params = list(ntrees = c(1,2,3)))
grid <- h2o.getGrid("gbm_grid_id", sort_by = "auc", decreasing = T)
```

However, replace 'auc' with 'logloss' and decrease = F, and it's fine.

Comment: Iris is a multiclass problem, which is why AUC is not supported in your example above.  The error message prints exactly the metrics that are supported for multiclass: `Invalid argument for sort_by specified. Must be one of: [r2, mean_per_class_accuracy, max_per_class_error, err, total_rows, rmse, accuracy, err_count, logloss, mse, mean_per_class_error]
`

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunately the H2O grid function uses training_frame not validation_frame when you pass them both in.  Consequently the winning model is extremely overfitted and useless. EDIT: Well, correction here, it's actually useful to have training bias very low like this, for purposes of learning curve analysis and bias versus variance analyi. But to be clear I also need to be able to run again and get a validation dataset to be used as search criterion for final model fitting and selection.

For example here is a winning model from the grid function on a GBM, where validation_frame was passed in, and AUC was the search metric.  You can see that the validation_auc starts at 0.5 and actually worsens to 0.44 on the final scoring history of the winning model:

```
Scoring History: 
            timestamp          duration number_of_trees training_rmse
1 2017-02-06 10:09:19  6 min 13.153 sec               0       0.70436
2 2017-02-06 10:09:23  6 min 16.863 sec             100       0.70392
3 2017-02-06 10:09:27  6 min 20.950 sec             200       0.70343
4 2017-02-06 10:09:31  6 min 24.806 sec             300       0.70289
5 2017-02-06 10:09:35  6 min 29.244 sec             400       0.70232
6 2017-02-06 10:09:39  6 min 33.069 sec             500       0.70171
7 2017-02-06 10:09:43  6 min 37.243 sec             600       0.70107
  training_logloss training_auc training_lift training_classification_error
1          2.77317      0.50000       1.00000                       0.49997
2          2.69896      0.99980      99.42857                       0.00026
3          2.62768      0.99980      99.42857                       0.00020
4          2.55902      0.99982      99.42857                       0.00020
5          2.49675      0.99993      99.42857                       0.00020
6          2.43712      0.99994      99.42857                       0.00020
7          2.38071      0.99994      99.42857                       0.00013
  validation_rmse validation_logloss validation_auc validation_lift
1         0.06921            0.03058        0.50000         1.00000
2         0.06921            0.03068        0.45944         9.03557
3         0.06922            0.03085        0.46685         9.03557
4         0.06922            0.03107        0.46817         9.03557
5         0.06923            0.03133        0.45656         9.03557
6         0.06924            0.03163        0.44947         9.03557
7         0.06924            0.03192        0.44400         9.03557
  validation_classification_error
1                         0.99519
2                         0.00437
3                         0.00656
4                         0.00656
5                         0.00700
6                         0.00962
7                         0.00962
```

Comment: H2O does not tell you the version when you run library(h2o), but it would be helpful in cases like this.  H2O does not have a function like h2o.version either, but that would also be helpful in cases like this.

Comment: H2O cluster version:        3.10.1.1 from h2o.init()

Comment: I don't think this is answering the question (about how to retrieve an ordering of the models). If you are seeing a problem with validation_frame being ignored, I'd suggest deleting this answer and starting a new question, with a fully reproducible example.

Comment: @GeoffreyAnderson We don't need a special function in H2O to get the package version; that's what `packageVersion()` in R is for.  Just type: `packageVersion("h2o")` or `h2o.init()` to see the version number.

Comment: @GeoffreyAnderson H2O's algos do use the validation frame for early stopping. The model stops after the early stopping criteria are met, but doesn't provide an additional pruning step to find the highest AUC for the trees built so far. In other words the model saw that after the a specified # consecutive `stopping_rounds` the AUC didn't improve by a specified `stopping_tolerance`. At that point it had built X trees with a certain score so that is the score it returns. It doesn't return the highest score, because the highest score in your example corresponds to a different number of trees.

Comment: @Lauren If H2O does not offer a way to return the model with the highest validation_auc, then H2O is not helping as much as it should.  History round 1 / score 0.5 is associated with the best model in the H2O output which I provided above.

Comment: @Erin L. H2O cluster version: 3.10.1.1 from h2o.init() – Geoffrey Anderson Feb 7

Comment: @Darren Cook the ordering of models by metric needs to respect the validation_frame to find the best model.  The title of the article is H2O R api: retrieving optimal model from grid search.

Comment: @Darren Cook re: " starting a new question, with a fully reproducible example. "  Please see the forum at h2o.ai for such.  If you want fully reproducible then you have to pay me with more than mere downvotes at stackexchange.

Comment: @GeoffreyAnderson sorry for the confusion, I was referring to a single model based on your community.h2o.ai question, but the q you posted here is for a grid, in which case you can explicitly select for the best AUC. Hope that clarifies things. Here's an example for selecting best auc from a grid search https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-tutorials/blob/master/h2o-open-tour-2016/chicago/grid-search-model-selection.R#L160

Comment: @GeoffreyAnderson StackOverflow is a Q&A forum. I stand by my comment that your "answer" is not answering the question, but reporting a possible bug (in which case it belongs on H2O's Jira, or the H2O mailing list), or asking for clarification about something, in which case it should be a question, not an answer. As for reproducible examples, and good questions, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve