# GridSearch API in H2O

Tags: java, scala, machine-learning, h2o, hyperparameters

I'm trying to use the `GridSearch` api within Scala for [H2O](http://www.h2o.ai/).  I have found [this](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/f49448bebbe9efc684e389b6d49497297b65f467/h2o-docs/src/product/grid-search.rst) documentation which shows what to do in R and Python but the Java documentation stops before actually getting the best model.  Can someone tell me the last few lines?  IE given a `Grid<MP>` how can I either get the best hyperparameter combinations or the best model?

EDIT

Here is how my code looks so far (it's in Scala but obviously I'm calling into the Java code within H2O).

```
private[this] def hyperopt(hyperParams: Map[String, Array[Object]]): M = {
  val search = GridSearch.startGridSearch(
    null,
    params,
    hyperParams.asJava,
    new SimpleParametersBuilderFactory[P],
    new HyperSpaceSearchCriteria.RandomDiscreteValueSearchCriteria)
  val grid = search.get().asInstanceOf[Grid[P]]
  val scoringInfo = grid.getScoringInfos.last // This is best scoringInfo cause it gets sorted along the way
  //val bestParams = scoringInfo.???
  //grid.getModel(bestParams).asInstanceOf[M]
}
```

The key problem is I don't know how to write the last 2 lines.

So after some digging I've come up with this solution which I don't like, but which does work

```
private[this] def hyperopt(hyperParams: (Map[String, Array[Object]], String)): M = {
  val search = GridSearch.startGridSearch(
    null,
    params,
    hyperParams._1.asJava,
    new SimpleParametersBuilderFactory[P],
    new HyperSpaceSearchCriteria.RandomDiscreteValueSearchCriteria)
  val grid = search.get()
  val summary = grid.createSummaryTable(grid.getModelKeys, hyperParams._2, true)

  info("Hyper parameter results")
  info(summary.toString)

  // TODO Fix this hack.  I don't know a better way to do this now.
  val bestModelId = summary.get(0, 1)
  grid.getModels.find(m => m._key.toString == bestModelId).get.asInstanceOf[M]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If memory serves, Grid grid = (Grid) gs.get(), returns you a complete grid. Now, what constitutes the best model? If you say that's the highest ROC, then sort the list by descending "auc" and select first element - much like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35657989/h2o-r-api-retrieving-optimal-model-from-grid-search).

Comment: This is exactly what I thought.  I dug deeply into the `ScoringInfo` code and found that the scoring results are indeed sorted, however, I see no way to correlate the `ScoringInfo`s with either the `Model` or the params which is the key element I'm missing.  Your post looks like it's the answer in R, but I was hoping to find it in Java.

Comment: The Model exposes ScoringInfo as a public property: https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-core/src/main/java/hex/Model.java#L619.

Comment: This is correct, but I don't want to have to traverse through each Model using `grid.getModels()` and compare the best `ScoringInfo` to each Model's scoring info, that seems hacky.  It just seems strange that the `Grid` object doesn't expose a method called something like `getBestParams` which is what I was initially looking for.  I've updated my question with some more info.